# Calculating physical distance scrolled from scrollWheel NSEvent

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, swift5

Making my first Swift app for macOS. Learning as I go...

I'm trying to make an app that calculates the total physical distance scrolled from a scrollwheel NSEvent handler. I'm using this code to attach the event handler:

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.scrollWheel, handler: self.scrollWheel);
```

I'm getting the absolute deltaY value in the event handler by using `let deltaY = abs(event.scrollingDeltaY)`

I'm guessing the deltaY is reported in points, but how do I translate it to a physical distance (in inch)?

I'm manually calculating the ppi for the user's device using this code:

```
let width = NSScreen.main?.frame.width ?? 0
let height = NSScreen.main?.frame.height ?? 0
      
let diagonal = sqrt(pow(width, 2) + pow(height, 2))
let pixelsPerInch = ((width / CGDisplayScreenSize(CGMainDisplayID()).width) * 25.4) * CGFloat(NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor ?? 0
```

I'm using this formula to calculate the physical distance scrolled (in inches).

```
let distance = deltaY *  1 / pixelsPerInch * 40
```

The formula is hardcoded and obviously wrong. The multiplication by 40 is an approximation, as I have no idea if I'm on the right track. I'm looking for the right formula.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're close

`CGDisplayScreenSize().width` gives you the physical width in mm.
`CGDisplayBounds().width` gives you the width number of pixels.
And 1 inch = 25.4 mm

So:
`let pixelsPerInch = CGDisplayBounds().width / ( CGDisplayScreenSize().width / 25.4 ))`
...and...
`let distance = deltaY / pixelsPerInch`